# how to display 3 column news layout

Tags: php, html

I have 11 news then i want to display like

1. first column need only one news
2. second column need 5 news
3. third column need the rest of 5 news

I tried this but no luck, it shows first column and second column and the rest outside column

```html
$rows = array(
                            'Title1',
                            'Title2',
                            'Title3',
                            'Title4',
                            'Title5',
                            'Title6',
                            'Title7',
                            'Title8',
                            'Title9',
                            'Title10',
                            'Title11',
                        );

                        $total_rows = count($rows);
                        $total_cols  = $total_rows - 1;// remove first one for the first column
                        $left_column = ceil($total_cols / 2);
                        $right_column = $total_cols - $left_column;

                        $i = 0;
echo "<div class='row'>";
                        foreach ($rows as $row) {
                            $i++;
                            if ($i == 1) {
                                $class = "primary_post";
                                echo "<div class='col-md-4 main'>";
                            } elseif ($i <= $left_column) {
                                $class = "other_post";
                                echo "<div class='col-md-4 left'>";
                            } elseif ($i == $right_column) {
                                $class = "other_post";
                                echo "<div class='col-md-4 right'>";
                            } else {
                                $class = "other_post";
                            }

                            echo "<div class='card {$class}'>$i</div>";
                            if ($i == 1 || $i == $left_column || $i == $right_column) {
                                echo "</div>";
                            } else {
                                echo "";
                            }
                        }
                        echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Sorry but I didn't see any mysql query.

Comment: Instead i added temporary array [$rows]

Comment: Your last echo "</div>"; supposed to be in the FOR loop not outside of it.

Comment: Also if you know the exact number of items why don't you loop just between numbers? It would be cleaner code.

Comment: @siniradam, what do yo mean by looping between numbers

Answer (score -1):

The last `echo "</div>";` supposed to be in the FOR loop not outside of it.

Also, you can split the array into chunks;

```
$firstColumn = array_splice($rows,0,1);
$secondColumn = array_splice($rows,0,5);
```

Rest are in the $rows variable.

So instead of dealing with ifs in for loops, you can use 3 different loops and list items in desired HTML objects.